# Automatically run Git hook when creating a Git tag

Tags: git, task, githooks, git-tag

Is there a Git hook which can be executed when a new Git tag is added? Because I want to automatically write new Git tag names into a textfile. Do you have a clue on how to do this?

Comment: For the record, `git tag` prints a list of all tags. I'm not sure I see it being easier to read a text file than to run that command and grab the output.

Answer (score 4):

While it's not currently possible using hooks, you can always create a simple script.

mytag.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -z "$1" ] || ( git tag $1 && git tag > /path/to/your-tags-file )
```

then :

```
chmod +x mytag.sh
git config alias.mytag !/path/to/mytag.sh
```

Comment: And you could alias a git command to this, of course. (To avoid any potential weirdness, you might want to just use `git tag > tags-file`, writing the whole list every time.)

Comment: It's not quite right. It could be done via hooks, check this SO question as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809910/how-do-i-react-to-new-tags-in-git-hooks