# How do I react to new tags in git hooks?

Tags: git, githooks

I'd like to set up a git hook that creates a CDN-style directory structure based on incoming tags. So, for example, if the last tag in the local repository is "v1.2.1" and I pull a commit with "v1.2.2", it should see the new tag and clone the repository into a new directly (../1.2.2) accordingly.

I'm pretty sure I want to attach this to post-receive, however I can't find anything in the documentation about git hooks about how to read the incoming tags. Are they delivered on a different hook? Do I actually need to have the shell script run a git command to see if any of the new commits have new tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Tags are refs like any other (like commit).
If tags are pushed to a repo with a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive), that hook will be called and will list all updated refs, that is both old and new values of all the refs in addition to their names (on its standard input).

See this server [post-receive email](https://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/post-receive-email) hook for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

. $(dirname $0)/functions

process_ref() {
    oldrev=$(git rev-parse $1)
    newrev=$(git rev-parse $2)
    refname="$3"

    set_change_type
    set_rev_types
    set_describe_tags

    case "$refname","$rev_type" in
      refs/tags/*,tag)
        # annotated tag
        refname_type="annotated tag"
        function="atag"
        short_refname=${refname##refs/tags/}
        # change recipients
        if [ -n "$announcerecipients" ]; then
          recipients="$announcerecipients"
        fi
      ;;
    esac 
}

while read REF; do process_ref $REF; done
```

For this to work you also must install [the functions file](https://github.com/stephenh/git-central/blob/master/server/functions) from the aforementioned example hook repository.

Comment: `$1, $2, and $3` are all null for me when I push a tag.

Comment: I fixed up the example in the answer so that it is a complete bash script, for those like me who are too lazy to follow the post-receive link

Comment: It's important to note that not all git repos will send a post-receive message back. To do a post receive hook with Atlassian Stash you need to do a lot more work.

Comment: @chovy: Some more prerequisites were missing in this particular paste of the original script. Ran into similar issues (`$refname`, `$ref_type` undefined), followed the original links and hopefully fixed it up now. VonC: Hope you do not mind the arguably aggressive edit.

Comment: @cfi Thank you so much for your edit. Much appreciated.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for the functions file reference! Now I feel compelled to go refactor my own post-receive hook.

Comment: Isn't `${refname##refs/tags/}` a bashism? In that case the shebang should be `#!/bin/bash` to prevent issues with systems linking `/bin/sh` to other shells (e.g. dash).

Comment: @SteenSchütt I agree, and have edited this (8 years-old) answer.