# Git hook that emails several people when a new tag is created

Tags: git

I am fairly new to git. I am familiar with all the basic commands and regular usage and all that. I am completely new to hooks.

I want a hook that when I create a tag it emails all the info about the tag to my project manager and QA lead. I tag every time a stable release is pushed to QA.

Workflow would look like this:

```
$ git tag -a v1.3
// Here git would then fire off all info on this new tag to several
// email addresses
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a hook for tags, but you could think about a job pushing regularely tags to a special cloned repo:

```
git push --tags
```

And you would setup a [post-receive hook](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html) able to detect any new tag and send the required email.
A bit like "[How do I react to new tags in git hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809910/how-do-i-react-to-new-tags-in-git-hooks)".