# How can we force git to always add tags as annotated

Tags: git

I need to force every new tag to be annotated tag. I need to force it to every user without telling them to do something special. I tried alias for tag to be "tag -a -m ''", but it doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder if this is possible with a git pre-receive hook on the server...

Comment: It is possible but I am not sure how good an idea -t would be to convert lightweight tags into annotated ones. What I suggested below could be done on the developer box/client end to help but even I am looking for suggestions on this. Interesting thing that came up during this was that how do you actually differentiate a lightweight tag from an annotated one. One can differentiate it if he views it but how do I know it from git itself or programatically(unless no ugly hack is involved).

Answer (score 1):

In .gitconfig, you can create an alias under a different name:

```
[alias]
    atag = tag -a -m ""
```

Then `git atag` creates an annotated tag. Not exactly elegant, but better than having to pass the -m each time.

Answer (score 0):

`git` won't let you force some policy for each of your users - say, provide a global alias or default flags for everyone who clones your repo.

What it will let you do is to enforce some policy on some specific repository you manage. Instead of making everyone auto-add those flags, you can use some [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for rejecting any push that includes a tag that's not annotated.

I don't really know how you can tell if the tag is annotated or not, but probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810488/641451) may help you to start playing with them.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this hack. Let every git command  pass through a shell script which will look for the command fired against git. If it's the "tag" command, make every lightweight tag into an annotated tag. If the command is not "tag", let normal operation continue as it is. Following code may help you.

```
 #!/bin/bash

    git_command=$1

    if [ "${git_command}" == "tag" ]; then
       echo "User is trying to tag"
       if [ "$2" != "-a" ] && [ "$2" != "-m" ]
       then
          echo lightweight
          echo "Second option is not -a nor -m.So looks like user is trying to create a lighweight tag."
          tag_message=$2
          git tag -a ${tag_message} -m ""
       else
          git tag $2 $3 $4 $5
          echo "Second option is either -a or -m. So may be user is trying to create an annotated tag."
       fi
    else
      echo "User is not tagging. So continue with the git operation user requested."
    fi
```