# How to determine who pushed a specific local tag to the remote Git repository

Tags: git

We have a team of developers using Git and SourceTree and we have some tags on the remote repository we are trying to delete.

We have deleted the tags on the remote repository and have 'supposedly' all deleted the tags locally.
However the tags seem to keep getting pushed to the remote and well all get them again.

We need a way to determine which developer is not deleting the tags locally and keeps pushing them up.

Is there way of determining who pushed up specific tags last?

Comment: You don't want...tags?  Okay...well, Git doesn't keep the history of who pushed what tags upstream.  What I'd recommend is an audit of everyone's flow of pushing tags in general.  You'd likely find the culprit as being a misunderstanding on how to appropriately push the recent tag.

Comment: Hi Makoto, We do use tags, there are just some tags we no longer want (named in an old format). We have tried ensuring each developer has deleted them locally but someone obviously isn't. I was hoping there was a git command that could tell us this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a update hook on the server that prohibits/logs when tags are pushed.

See [Tag Detection hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809910/how-do-i-react-to-new-tags-in-git-hooks) as a sample to get you started.