# Git: how do you know who pushed a tag?

Tags: git

Some one in my team pushed a useless tag to remote, and I deleted it in my local working copy then pushed it to remote, the tag disappeared.

But before I deleted this tag, many people had already pulled this tag to their local working copy, anyone who pushes again(by selecting the "push all tags" in SourceTree) will recreate these tags.

By using `git show <tagname>`, I can only see who create the tag the first time, but how can I find who pushed the tag again?

Comment: Git itself doesn't store that information, but some hosting services (such as GitHub) do.

Comment: You might be able to setup a server side hook to delete it upon push, but then again, its going to get pushed again each time from everyone until they clean it out of their local repos. OTOH, you might be able to use this to figure out who is pushing it and send them a warning to delete it locally.

Comment: Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809910/how-do-i-react-to-new-tags-in-git-hooks

Comment: How can GIT not retain this information important... and it does not provide a default way to get it...

Answer (score 10):

Even if you have annotated tags where the tagger is saved in the tag object, you still can't see who has pushed it unless you save it on the server at the time of pushing it. GitHub/GitLab Enterprise editions may provide this for you.

However, your root problem is that everyone need to delete that tag on their local machines so it's not pushed back up.

If people don't have local-only tags they can run the following to delete all local tags which are not found in the remote repository:

```
# Delete all local tags
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
# Fetch remote tags
git fetch -t
```

I hope that helps!