# GIT_COMMIT envvar incorrect for pipelines that merge master first

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Context**

This question relates to multibranch pipelines where the behaviour merges the PR with the target branch revision (see screenshot of settings)

[image: behaviours from multibranch settings]

In this case, the merge may cause a new merge commit. So for a trigger with a given commit from a repository:

[image: commit in blue ocean header]

We actually get a different value of the `GIT_COMMIT` envvar:

[image: printenv output showing GIT_COMMIT]

If a tool (such as a build reporting tool) needs to use the `GIT_COMMIT` envvar to pass information onto a service, it cannot then be linked back to the actual commit from the project (this is a screenshot from Bitbucket but this would be the same for any repo hosting service):

[image: not found commit on Bitbucket]

**Question**

How, in a pipeline step, can I find the commit `709502c` is the actual genesis of this build, when the `GIT_COMMIT` is set to `6781a3d1` (which is not an actual commit in the project)?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619550/6309 works better to get the right GIT_COMMIT?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe looking at `git` history can help?

```
REAL_GIT_COMMIT = sh (
            script: "git rev-parse HEAD",
            returnStdout: true,
    ).trim()
```

Comment: That will just give me the current commit, which will be the merge of master and my test branch. I could try HEAD~1 but I am not sure that's guaranteed to be the branch commit that's being tested, because if the merge was able to fast forward, GIT_COMMIT is correct.