# Need to run a "hook" on new Git Tag (Git hook for newly pulled tags)

Tags: bash, git, githooks

To begin, I looked at this question which seems to be the only one regarding this topic:

- [How do I react to new tags in git hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809910/how-do-i-react-to-new-tags-in-git-hooks)

But I do not understand what hook that is or how it is being used. I simply want to run a little script that will update if I `git pull` **and new tag are received.**

I tried putting it in: `.git/hooks/update`, `.git/hooks/post-receive`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec < /dev/tty

CURRENT_TAG=$(git tag --contains)
echo Test Test
echo "LATEST_TAG: \"${CURRENT_TAG}"\" > "config/latest_tag.yml"
```

I would like to use Git hooks if possible. I was thinking of doing `alias "git pull"="git pull && ./update_script.sh` but I cannot alias a spaced word, n'or can I alias something and enforce the rest of the team to remember it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation says](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive), the post-receive and update hooks are "server" side hooks, i.e. they run on the server in reaction to a push from a client. What you want is the opposite, for which there unfortunately is no hook.

Since you mention that aliasing the command wouldn't work, you could use a function as the next best thing. It will receive the arguments that can then be examined.

```
git() { env git $* && [ "$1" = "fetch" -o "$1" = "pull" ] && ./update_script.sh; }
```

Care must be taken when shadowing commands like this to not cause infinite recursion. Within the function body, you must never call `git` directly, as that would re-run the function, not the `git` command. I've used `env` to resolve the actual `git` binary, but using an absolute path would work just as well.

Note that it is actually `git fetch` that will get the new tags and `git pull` simply calls `git fetch` internally. I therefore included handling for both `fetch` and `pull`. Also note that it will shadow the git command in all repositories, so it would need to be extended if the special handling should only be applied to specific repositories.

In case your `update_script.sh` is tracked within the repository itself there are at least two things to be aware of:

- **Anyone who can push changes** to that file will essentially be **enabled to run arbitrary commands** on any machine where pulls happen.
- As the `pull` or `fetch` commands may be run anywhere in the work tree, not just at the top level, the path should first be resolved using `[env] git rev-parse --show-toplevel`.

Comment: This answer could not have been more perfect. I read preciously and took careful precautions. Your `git()` bash function was (in my case) the best solution. When you say _may be run anywhere in the work tree_, do you mean anywhere in the repo (ie. project/server/db` or anywhere on the computer? I couldn't think why you would want it only on the toplevel of the repo.

Comment: Working tree / working copy is just the technical term for the actually checked out files from your repo, the repo itself, strictly speaking, only resides within `.git`. Your `./update_script.sh` is using a relative path and since you would call `git pull` somewhere in your work tree, it implies that the script is part of the repo. Having a relative path of just `.` means you'd need to run your `git pull` at the same level where the script is. Using `$(env git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/update_script.sh` would instead allow to run `git pull` from any level.